# Python - find substring in a string (code not working)

Tags: python

I'm writing a code, where you input a string (i) and a substring (sb) and the code should count the amount of times the substring appears in the string, with overlaps.

The code works if you input string "AAAA" and look for "A" ((returns the correct amount, 4) but if you put in "ADAM" and look for "A" it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

For the life of me, I cant solve this problem.

```
i = input("Enter a string:")
sb = input("Enter a substring:")

count = 0
x = 0    #index from the string found
idxTotal = len(i)  

while True:

    i.find(sb,x)

    if x != idxTotal:
        count += 1
        x = i.find(sb,x)+1

    else:
        break

print(count)
```

Comment: If `i.find(sb,x)` doesn't find your substring, it will return `-1`, which will put you back at the beginning of the string. You should check what it returned and break your loop if it returns `-1`.

Comment: Do you want to know why your code doesn't work, or do you just want a working solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the -1 means 'False' therefore, the 'while' block should be skipped, and go straight to the print command, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Metal.days You're wrong. `-1` doesn't mean false, and even if it did, there's nothing in the code that would skip the `while` block in that circumstance. Your code will loop forever until it hits a `break`, and because `x` can get reduced down to zero from `x = i.find(sb,x)+1`, you won't hit the break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you make things too complicated. Basically you should check in the `while` loop that we did not reach the end of the string. Furthermore you should *guarantee* progress, by incrementing the offset value.

So we can write it like:

```
x = i.find(sb)
n = 0
while x >= 0:
    n += 1
    x = i.find(sb, x+1)
# here n is the number of occurrences
print(n)
```

So first we perform a `i.find(sb)` to find the first occurrence, and we set `n` (the count) to zero, each time `x >= 0`, we found a next occurrence, so then we increment `n`, and then we look for the next occurrence.

We keep doing that until `.find(..)` returns `-1`. In that case the `while` loop will stop, and `n` will contain the number of elements.

For example:

```
>>> i = 'ADAM'
>>> sb = 'A'
>>> x = i.find(sb)
>>> n = 0
>>> while x >= 0:
...     n += 1
...     x = i.find(sb, x+1)
...
>>> print(n)
2
```

This also performs overlap counts, like:

```
>>> i = 'AAADAAAAAM'
>>> sb = 'AAA'
>>> x = i.find(sb)
>>> n = 0
>>> while x >= 0:
...     n += 1
...     x = i.find(sb, x+1)
...
>>> print(n)
4
```

So here for `'AAADAAAAAM'` there are four matches with `'AAA'`:

```
  AAADAAAAAM
1 AAA
2     AAA
3      AAA
4       AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,

```
some_string = input("Enter a string:")
some_substring = input("Enter a substring:")
total = 0
for index, some_char in enumerate(some_string):
  # print(index, some_char) # try this to see what comes in the loop
  if some_string[index:].startswith(some_substring):
    total = total + 1

print(total)
```

It is more elegant, avoid using while(True) also i.find will return -1 therefore you will be stuck in infinite loop. This will allow you to avoid manually indexing with while. :)

This will work for "ADAM" and "A" with correct 2 and also for other substrings like "DABCEABC" and "ABC" with correct 2, "AAADAAAAAM" and "AAA" with the correct 5.

Comment: I dont mean to print them, just providing a better way to do things. How does op get help by doing a while loop, when a sequential for loop over enumerate gives the same construct

Comment: Also the error is in indexing, thus this is a valid and better solution as it avoids manual indexing

Comment: It's not a valid and better solution if it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: A loop and "do something like count" isn't really much of an answer.

Comment: Ok I edited it to add a working solution as well, the title said code not working so initially I just debugged it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the find method returns -1 when no substring is found, I would use that to end your while loop.

By doing the following you count until the substring isn't found anymore:

```
i = input("Enter a string:")
sb = input("Enter a substring:")

count = 0
x = 0  

while True:
    x = i.find(sb,x)+1  #x will be 0 if sb isn't found
    if x != 0:          #if x = 0 the while loop will end
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print(count)
```

Answer (score -4):

Below code will work as per your needs:

`i.count(sb,0,len(i))`

Comment: That doesn't support overlapping occurrences of the substring.

Comment: This will only perform non-overlapping matches.